# Issues with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to use ggplot2 to make a stacked bar chart. But here are some issues for the final output.
The code is:

```
    Year <- c(rep(2010 , 2) , rep(2011 , 2) , rep(2012 , 2) , rep(2011 , 2) , rep(2014 , 2) , rep(2015 , 2) ,
                rep(2016 , 2) , rep(2017 , 2) , rep(2018 , 2) , rep(2019 , 2), rep(2020 , 2))
    
    Station <- rep(c("A" , "B") , 11)
    
    Word_count <- c(953571370424 
    ,809037391432 
    ,2075147269145 
    ,1218737285053 
    ,1603217393995 
    ,1540346123643 
    ,1371431865986 
    ,1609941622714 
    ,1572262756583 
    ,923392384249 
    ,1164562649251 
    ,776375099501 
    ,1956027215966 
    ,1304018143978 
    ,901078272828 
    ,763759731204 
    ,665935201613 
    ,998902802419 
    ,1359486135828 
    ,1359486135828 
    ,1157186353212 
    ,771457568808 
    )
    data <- data.frame(Year,Station,Word_count)
    
    print(data)
    
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Word_count))+
      geom_col(aes(fill = Station), width = 0.7)
    p
```

[image]

There is a problem with the spacing between these bar charts, the X coordinate I want to show each year, but the result is not (It skips some years and also has results like 2010.5). the stacked part of Y I want to show the absolute value of 'word_count' in the figure, but how should I show the specific word count value in the stacked bar chart?

I am learning visualization in R. I would appreciate and be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a typo? - two lots of 2011 and none for 2013

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve would be to use `as.factor()` for the x axis and using `geom_text` to show the count:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Word_count, fill = Station))+
  geom_col(width = 0.9)+
  xlab("Year")+
  geom_text(aes(label = formatC(Word_count, format = "e")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]